# Jquery atualização de dados

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho uma dúvida pertinente quanto a atualização de forma dinâmica:

Possuo um sistema de pedidos.

O problema é que os valores não estão sendo somados corretamente no evento de click.

[image: registro de pedidos]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na primeira imagem eu apenas clico no botão "+" e a caixa de texto adiciona o número.

Na segunda o valor do pedido recebe todo o valor já somado.

**HTML**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media-body">
  <div class="menu-tittle">
</div>
  <div class="quantity">
    <form action="#">
      <div class="pizza-add-sub">
        <input type="text" class="qtdpedidos" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="pizza-price"> <span class="pizza">10.00</span>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Valor do Pedido: R$<span class="resultado">0.00</span></p>
```

**JS**

```
 $(".pizza-add-sub").append('<div class="plus qty-pizza">+</div><div class="mines qty-pizza">-</div>');
$(".qty-pizza").on("click", function() {

var $button = $(this);
var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();
if ($button.text() == "+") {
  var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
} else {
  // Don't allow decrementing below zero
 if (oldValue > 0) {
    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
    } else {
    newVal = 0;
  }
  }
$button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
var total = 0;
var valorPizza = $('.pizza').text().substring(0, $('.pizza').text().indexOf('.'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  
     $(".pizza-add-sub").append('<div class="plus qty-pizza">+</div><div class="mines qty-pizza">-</div>');
     $(".qty-pizza").on("click", function() {
     
     var $button = $(this);
     var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();
  if ($button.text() == "+") {
    var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
  } else {
    // Don't allow decrementing below zero
    if (oldValue > 0) {
       var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
       } else {
       newVal = 0;
     }
  }
     $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);
  var v1 = $('#item1 span').text();
  var v2 = Number(document.getElementById("qtdpedidos").value);
     document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = parseFloat(v1 * v2).toFixed(2);
 
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#">
<div class="media-body">
  <div class="menu-tittle">
</div>
  <div class="quantity">
    
      <div class="pizza-add-sub">
        <input type="text" id="qtdpedidos" class="qtdpedidos" value="0"/>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="item1" class="pizza-price"> <span id="pizza" class="pizza">10.00</span>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<p>Valor do Pedido: R$<span id="resultado" class="resultado">0.00</span></p>
```